# Accessing database table in Django view template

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I've been unable to read objects from a local SQLite database in my Django app in a particular instance (but have been able to read other data from the same database in a similar instance).

In `/blog/views.py` there are two functions defined, one to get all the instances of `Article` (`index`), and one to show some details of a particular `Article` (`detail`). `detail` is working as expected; i.e., I can navigate to `localhost/xxxx/blog/1`, and it will display the `Article`'s `title` and `description`. However, on the `index` page (which is routed to just `localhost/xxxx/blog/`), the object `latest_article_list` is not loaded, as "No articles are available" is displayed. The latter means that the routing is working, but it's just not reading `Article.objects.all()`.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Article, Tags, Author


def index(request):
    """
    Will render templates/blog/index.html when called.
    This should show all articles.
    """
    latest_article_list = Article.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', {'latest_article_list': latest_article_list})


def detail(request, article_id):
    """
    Render templates/blog/detail.html.
    Returns article object.
    """
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=article_id)
    return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', {'article': article})
```

**detail.html** (working as expected, returns Article.title and Article.description for a given primary key)

```
{% block content %}
<br />
<h1> {{ article.title }} </h1>
<p> {{ article.description }} </p>
{% endblock %}
```

**index.html** (not working as expected, `if latest_article_list` is evaluating to FALSE)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<br />
<h1> Blog posts </h1>

{% if latest_article_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for article in latest_article_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'blog:detail' article.id %}">{{ article.description }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>
        No articles are available.
    </p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

In **blog/models.py**

```
from from django.db import models

default_author_id = 1
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # foreign key to author
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               default=default_author_id)
    description = models.TextField()
    publication_date = models.DateTimeField('Published')
    image = models.FilePathField(path='static/blog/images/')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('publication_date',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I should add that if I use the terminal to check the database for `Article`s, I can return them fine:

```
py manage.py shell
from <...>/models import Article
Article.objects.all()
# <QuerySet [<Article: article1>, <Article: article2>]>
```

I'm loosely following the [official Django tutorials](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial03/).

Comment: Check your templates and urls.py for duplicates or such, nothing's wrong with the presented code afaic.

Comment: Something is missing to understand what's the issue, it should work. maybe another `index` view in your file ? or the wrong template directory ?

Comment: Well that's interesting then, glad I'm not going crazy at least! There is one other `index.html` template, but it returns a completely different view. `templates/blog/index.html` is the only template with this code. I didn't post all of it originally, so I'll edit it now to add a couple of lines (just `extends` and `load static`, so I don't think they're relevant).

Comment: 1) Will probably not fix this but `{% for %}{% empty %}` exists for this type of cases. 2) Put `pdb.set_trace()` after defining `latest_article_list` in `index`. There, inspect the variable's value, try filtering there and check what happens 3) Name your keyword argument for `render`: `render(request, 'blog/index.html', context={ ... })`.